# How can I remove empty factors from ggplot2 facets?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to modify an [example of a simple forest](http://statbandit.wordpress.com/2010/11/01/forest-plots-using-r-and-ggplot2/) plot by introducing facets according to a  factor variable.

Assuming data of this structure:

```
test <- structure(list(characteristic = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L
), .Label = c("Factor1", "Factor2", "Factor3"), class = "factor"), 
    es = c(1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.3, 1.5), ci_low = c(1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 
    1.2, 1.4), ci_upp = c(1.3, 1.5, 1.7, 1.4, 1.6), label = structure(c(1L, 
    3L, 5L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("1.2 (1.1, 1.3)", "1.3 (1.2, 1.4)", 
    "1.4 (1.3, 1.5)", "1.5 (1.4, 1.6)", "1.6 (1.5, 1.7)"), class = "factor"), 
    set = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("H", "S"
    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("characteristic", "es", 
"ci_low", "ci_upp", "label", "set"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

And running the code:

```
p <- ggplot(test, aes(x=characteristic, y=es, ymin=ci_low, ymax=ci_upp)) + geom_pointrange() +
  coord_flip() + geom_hline(aes(x=0), lty=2) + 
  facet_wrap(~ set, ncol = 1) +
  theme_bw() + 
  opts(strip.text.x = theme_text())
```

Produces output like that:

[image]

All good so far. However, I'd like to get rid of empty Factor3 level from my lower panel and cannot find a way to do that. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks for help.

Comment: When referencing R I stopped asking "Is there..." and started asking "How can I..."  `install.packages("fortunes"); library(fortunes); fortune("Yoda")`

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**EDIT** Updated to ggplot2 0.9.3

Here's another solution. It uses `facet_grid` and `space = "free"`; also it uses `geom_point()` and `geom_errorbarh()`, and thus there is no need for `coord.flip()`. Also, the x-axis tick mark labels appear on the lower panel only. In the code below, the `theme` command is not essential - it is used to rotate the strip text to appear horizontally. Using the `test` dataframe from above, the following code should produce what you want:

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(test, aes(y = characteristic, x = es, xmin = ci_low, xmax = ci_upp)) +
   geom_point() +
   geom_errorbarh(height = 0) +
   facet_grid(set ~ ., scales = "free", space = "free") +
   theme_bw() +
   theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 0))

p
```

The solution is based on the example on page 124 in Wickham's ggplot2 book.

Answer (score 28):

Use `scales = "free"` as in:

```
p <- ggplot(test, aes(x=characteristic, y=es, ymin=ci_low, ymax=ci_upp)) + geom_pointrange() +
  coord_flip() + geom_hline(aes(x=0), lty=2) + 
  facet_wrap(~ set, ncol = 1, scales="free") +
  theme_bw() + 
  opts(strip.text.x = theme_text())

p
```

Which produces:

[image]

EDIT:  I actually think I like the `drop = TRUE` argument better for this solution as in:

```
p <- ggplot(test, aes(x=characteristic, y=es, ymin=ci_low, ymax=ci_upp)) + 
  geom_pointrange() +
  coord_flip() + geom_hline(aes(x=0), lty=2) + 
  facet_wrap(~ set, ncol = 1,  drop=TRUE) +
  theme_bw() + 
  opts(strip.text.x = theme_text())

p
```

Comment: Excellent! Worked as a charm. One question though: Will panels always be of a proportionate size (vertically)? Is there.. Not - How can I scale them according to the number of factors used by each? For instance - if I have 10 in upper panel, and 3 in lower?

Comment: I think `space = "free"` is the other argument you're looking for.

Comment: I think `space = "free"` argument is for [facet_grid](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/facet_grid.html). However `scales = 'free_x'` doesn't work any longer there :/

Comment: How can this be done with out causing the scale of the axis to expand? In this example notice the space between the Factor1 and Factor 2 gridline is different between the top and bottom. It's not so noticeable here but when creating a stacked barchart, the widths of the bars will now be much different between the facet panels depending on how many factors in the axis get dropped. This one has me stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a note that drop = TRUE did not work for me, but scales = TRUE did. Probably could be related to some specifics of my code.