# removing unused factors from facet_grid with row and column specified

Tags: r, ggplot2

**What is the Problem?**

Each facet in ggplot2 may not contain all factor levels in the 'name' column, in which case I want the facet to ignore those factor levels to avoid the gaps in the tiles.

**What have I tried**

I have tried adding and removing `scales = "free"`, `drop = TRUE`, and `space = "free"` from `facet_grid` as recommended in a stackexchange question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24806/dropping-unused-levels-in-facets-with-ggplot2), and a stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183292/how-can-i-remove-empty-factors-from-ggplot2-facets).

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Example slice of data**

```
test_data <- structure(list(sample = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3"), name = c("IV_1385127_1385127_1_+_3_1", 
"IV_78222_78222_1_-_3_1", "XV_978130_978130_1_-_3_1", "XIV_574351_574351_1_+_3_1", 
"XV_357215_357215_1_-_3_1", "XII_456601_456601_1_-_3_1", "V_423552_423552_1_+_3_1", 
"XI_200191_200191_1_-_3_1", "XII_465717_465717_1_-_4_2", "XII_455342_455342_1_-_3_1", 
"VII_84298_84298_1_-_3_1", "IV_229884_229884_1_+_4_2", "XII_633371_633371_1_-_4_2", 
"XIII_9888_9888_1_-_4_2", "X_703096_703096_1_-_3_2", "IV_1385127_1385127_1_+_3_1", 
"IV_78222_78222_1_-_3_1", "XV_978130_978130_1_-_3_1", "XIV_574351_574351_1_+_3_1", 
"XV_357215_357215_1_-_3_1", "XII_456601_456601_1_-_3_1", "V_423552_423552_1_+_3_1", 
"XI_200191_200191_1_-_3_1", "XII_465717_465717_1_-_4_2", "XII_455342_455342_1_-_3_1", 
"VII_84298_84298_1_-_3_1", "IV_229884_229884_1_+_4_2", "XII_633371_633371_1_-_4_2", 
"XIII_9888_9888_1_-_4_2", "X_703096_703096_1_-_3_2"), ntile = c("1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "2", 
"2", "2", "2"), position = c("-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", 
"-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"
), base = c("T", "T", "T", "A", "C", "A", "T", "T", "A", "T", 
"T", "G", "C", "C", "A", "A", "G", "A", "G", "G", "A", "T", "A", 
"G", "T", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

**Code used for plotting**

```
  p <- ggplot(test_data, aes(x = position, y = factor(name))) +
      geom_tile(aes(fill = base)) +
      scale_fill_viridis_d() +
      theme_bw() +
      theme(
          axis.title.y=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y=element_blank(),
          legend.title=element_blank(),
          axis.title.x=element_text(margin = margin(t = 15)),
          panel.grid=element_blank()
       )

    p <- p + facet_grid(ntile ~ sample, scales = "free", space = "free", drop = TRUE)
```

**Example plot output**

[image: example plot]

**ggplot2 version**

ggplot2 3.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no unused factors in your sample data and the arguments are not giving you what you desire. Possible startup workaround can be:

```r
# Your script
p <- ggplot(test_data, aes(x = position, y = factor(name))) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = base)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(
    axis.title.y=element_blank(),
    axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
    legend.title=element_blank(),
    axis.title.x=element_text(margin = margin(t = 15)),
    panel.grid=element_blank()
  )
p + coord_flip() + facet_wrap(ntile ~ sample, scales = "free")
```

## output

[image: unused_factor_updated]

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Simply changing it from `facet_grid` to `facet_wrap` with `scales = "free"` seems to have done the trick.

Comment: In addition, `coord_flip() ` enables the factor choice.

Comment: For this particular plot I needed the x axis to be the positions labeled -1 and 1, so I excluded the `coord_flip()` for my final plot. It still seemed to work without it.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect the change.